# Break long string into pieces php

Tags: php, string, split

so I have a string which is around 3800 characters, it's sentences words etc.

Now I'm running the string through something although the limit is 1000, so how could I break the string into 4 pieces each containing a maximum of 1000 characters and not breaking words in half, is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `str_split`.

```
   $string = "the_long_string";
   $array = str_split($string, 1000); //$array will contain elements which each is 1000 chars long.
```

if you want words not to cut off transform it through `wordwrap` prior to cutting them as follows

```
 $string = "the_long_string";
 $string = wordwrap($string, 1000, "||"); //assume your string doesn't contain `||`
 $parts = explode("||", $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

`$parts = str_split($string, 1000);`

NOT sure about not breaking words in half though

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) for this

```
$first = substr($string, 0, 1000);
$second = substr($string, 1001, 2000);
$third = substr($string, 2001, 3000);
$fourth = substr($string, 3001, 3800);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with [`str_split()`](http://php.net/str_split):

Here's what I'd do:

```
<?php
$str = "sdasdasdsdkjsdkdjbskdbvksdbfksjdssssbfkdbfksdjbf";
$length = strlen($str);
$parts = str_split($str, $length/4);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    echo $part."<br>";
}    
?>
```

Will split the given string into 4 equal pieces and output:

```
sdasdasdsdkj
sdkdjbskdbvk
sdbfksjdssss
bfkdbfksdjbf
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) with an offset.

Something like

```
$fullstring = "3800 characters";
$pos = $last = 0;
while($pos !== FALSE && $last <= 1000) {
    $last = $pos;
    $pos = strpos($fullstring, " ", $pos) + 1;
}
```

This will continue looping until either $last is the last position of a space before the 1000th character, or there are no more characters.  You'll then just need to substr up to that position and assign to an array, substr the rest of the characters and overwrite $fullstring, and reset the counters to 0 (ie. add a loop around the code of `while (strlen($fullstring) > 0)`